# Extract table from an image

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, img2table

I have been trying to extract a table with [img2table](https://github.com/xavctn/img2table) and Tesseract but I always get no extracted tables no matter the different parameters I use. Why? How can I successfully extract the table from this type of image?

```py
from img2table.ocr import TesseractOCR
from img2table.document import Image

# Instantiation of OCR
ocr = TesseractOCR(n_threads=1, lang="eng")

# Instantiation of document, either an image or a PDF
src = "table.png"
doc = Image(src)

# Table extraction
extracted_tables = doc.extract_tables(ocr=ocr,
                                      implicit_rows=True,
                                      borderless_tables=True,
                                      min_confidence=50)

In [2]: extracted_tables
Out[2]: []
```

The image is:

[image: table]

Versions

```
img2table==1.2.8
opencv-python==4.9.0.80
pytesseract==0.3.10

❯ tesseract --version
tesseract 4.1.1
 leptonica-1.82.0
  libgif 5.1.9 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 2.1.1) : libpng 1.6.37 : libtiff 4.3.0 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 1.2.2 : libopenjp2 2.4.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE
 Found libarchive 3.6.0 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.5 bz2lib/1.0.8 liblz4/1.9.3 libzstd/1.4.8
```

Comment: 1) what would you suggest instead of using OCR?

Comment: 2) When I run `tesseract table.png output -l eng`, I get a bunch of non sense characters like these: `Ex) Ee) Ee) Py Ee)` Any idea why and you don't?

Comment: yes, I saw this commercial service. It looks pretty good but I was looking for something in-house where I keep control of the images.